# Use RedirectToAction without passing query string parameters/route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, routevalues

I have a "Thingy" controller for that looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long? id) {
    // <Validate ID, delete associated records>
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Thingy");
}
```

However, `RedirectToAction` keeps having its route values populated with the id from the parameters, whereas I want it to leave id as null so it redirects to `www.mywebsite.com/Thingy` instead of `www.mywebsite.com/Thingy/1`

In fact, I can visit `www.mywebsite.com/Thingy` directly and it works as expected.

I have tried:

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Thingy")
RedirectToAction("Index", "Thingy", new { })
RedirectToAction("Index", "Thingy", new { id = (long?)null })
```

The last is particularly amusing because it redirects to `www.mywebsite.com/Thingy?id=1` where as the others redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/Thingy/1`.

Comment: Try adding this before the redirect in your first example: `RouteData.Values.Remove("id");`.  I have a feeling the route values you specify are being merged with the original route values.

Comment: Brilliant, works. Make it an answer and I'll accept since it effectively fixes my issue.

Comment: I'm happy it works, I was in the middle of testing it when you commented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following before your `RedirectToAction()` in your first example:

```
RouteData.Values.Remove("id");
```

I have a feeling the route values you specify are being merged with the original route values.

Comment: Wow. It was difficult to find. +1